# Grouping and Std. Dev in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame called dt. dt looks like this.

```
Year Sale
2009  6
2008  3
2007  4
2006  5
2005  12
2004  3
```

I am interested in getting std.dev of sales in the past four years. In case, there are not four year data, as in 2006,2005, and 2004, I want to get NA. How can I create a new column with the values corresponding to each year. New data would look like.

```
 Year Sale  std.
2009  6     std(05,06,07,08)
2008  3     std(07,06,05,04)
2007  4     NA
2006  5     NA
2005  12    NA
2004  3     NA
```

I tried this a lot, but because I am a novice at R, I couldn't do it. Someone please help. Thanks.

Edit : 
Here is the data with GVKEY.

```
    GVKEY FYEAR    IBC
 1  1004  2003  3.504
 2  1004  2004 18.572
 3  1004  2005 35.163
 4  1004  2006 59.447
 5  1004  2007 75.745
```

Regards

Edit:

I am using the mentioned function rollapply function in this manner:

```
dt <- ddply(dt, .(GVKEY), function(x){x$ww <- rollapply(x$Sale,4,sd, fill =NA, align="right"); x});
```

But I am getting following error. 
`Error in seq.default(start.at, NROW(data), by = by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument`

Not sure what I am doing wrong. The data with GVKEY is mentioned at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
dt <- dt[order(dt$GVKEY,dt$FYEAR),]; 
  dt <- sqldf("select GVKEY, FYEAR, IBC from dt");
  dt$STDEARN <- ave(dt$IBC, dt$GVKEY,FUN = function(x) {if(length(x)>3) c(NA,head(runSD(x,4),-1)) else sample(NA,length(x),TRUE)});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rollapply` from package zoo:

```
require(zoo)
rollapply(df$Sale, 4, sd, fill=NA, align="right")
```

[edit] I used your data frame as sorted by year. If you have it in original order, you will probably need to use align="left"